# Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit.dll not found Issue while installing Tridion UI 2012

Tags: 2011, cme, experience-manager

I am installing **User interface update for SDL Tridion 2011 SP1** on SDL Tridion 2011 SP1 HR2. I installed it administrator and restarted the machine. Now when i try to load CME i am getting following issue.

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Tridion.Web.UI.Editors.SiteEdit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I had SiteEdit 2009 SP3 on this machine Earlier which i uninstalled first, and after uninstalling and before installing ui-2012 CME was loading perfectly.

Comment: Did you stop all (SDL Tridion) services before installing? If not try running repair (with all services stopped).

Comment: Yes i did, again tried but no luck.

Answer (score 3):

Just a FYI, not only does the msi update the files only in the default location (i.e. not the one specified by the user/environmen variables, but the default tridion /web folder) but the .msi also creates the virtual directory paths to all the /Site Edit directories there, so you'll want to update those references as well.

Comment: Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2):

After analysis i found there is an issue with `UIUpdate2012.msi'. Our tridion web/WebUI directory is on different location from Tridion CM root directory.

but msi copying all the required folders to Tridion CM folder rather than copying to Tridion web/UI.

It Seems msi reading environment variables instead of Windows Registry.